# Brand_title is not saved in database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making an insert mobile data page where for brands i had made dropdown menu the dropdown menu is working perfectly but when I insert mobile data brand id is inserted in database but brand title is not inserted why?

```
    // code for dropdown menu 
    <tr>
       <td style="color:#fff"><b>Mobile Brand</b></td>
   <td>
     <select name="Mbrand">
     <option>Select Brand</option>

 <?php 

         $get_brands = "select * from brands";

         $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

         while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands))
{

          $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
          $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

echo "<option value='$brand_id'>'$brand_title'</option>";

  }
?>

    </select>

    </td>
    </tr>
    ----------------------------
    // code for defining data
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['insert_mobile'])){
     //text data variables
    $mobile_title=$_POST['Mname'];
    $mobile_price=$_POST['Mprice'];
    $mobile_brand=$_POST['Mbrand'];
    $mobile_desc=$_POST['mdesc'];
    $mobile_keywords = $_POST['key'];

    -----------------------------
  //code for inserting data
    $insert_mobile = "insert into mobile_phone (mobile_name,brand_id,date,price,img1,img2,img3,mobile_desc,product_keywords)  values ('$mobile_title','$mobile_brand',NOW(),'$mobile_price','$mobile_img1','$mobile_img2','$mobile_img3','$mobile_desc','$mobile_keywords')";
     $run_mobile= mysqli_query($con,$insert_mobile);

    if($run_mobile)
{

        echo "<script>alert('mobile added successfully')</script>";
        exit();

 }
```

Comment: Is this all in the same file? Because if so, you'll need [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php).

Comment: Nowhere are you including a `$brand_title` form value that you could retrieve when the form is posted. I also don't see it anywhere in your insert statement. Normally you would store the ID of something only and not the actual title.

Comment: I have to store both title and id should i define title separately  ?

Comment: Please note, that if you are storing id and title in the table, it means that you are following any Database Normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using $brand_title instead of $brand_id in the option value.

```
echo "<option value='$brand_id'>'$brand_title'</option>";
```

will become

```
$brand = $brand_id.':'.$brand_title;
echo "<option value='$brand'>'$brand_title'</option>";
```

**Edit**

Option value is actually the one that gets passed in $_POST[] values and that can be stored in database as you need.

**Edit**
Replace the below code

```
 $mobile_brand=$_POST['Mbrand'];
```

with

```
$brand_id = explode(':', $_POST['Mbrand'])[0];
$brand_title = explode(':', $_POST['Mbrand'])[1];
```

And please change the Insert query accordingly, so that it can accomodate or store both **brand_id** and **brand_title** in respective columns. Please check the datatypes of those columns before you run the script.

Comment: now brand id and brand title both are not inserted?

Comment: so what will be the solution to define title separately?

Comment: What's the datatype for "brand_id" column in the database? It shouldn't be int or float.. It should be varchar ideally as it is a string.

Comment: ohh ok mine is int I will change and check

Comment: now brand title is saved in the place of brand id and brand title is empty

Comment: Query (insert into mobile_phone (mobile_name,brand_id,date,price,img1,img2,img3,mobile_desc,product_keywords)  values ('$mobile_title','$mobile_brand',NOW(),'$mobile_price','$mobile_img1','$mobile_img2','$mobile_img3','$mobile_desc','$mobile_keywords')) just inserts only one of them as I see.. you need to change the db structure so that it can store both id and title, then change the query to store both id and title. Please read my updated answer for other things you need to change.

Comment: please use explode instead of split and it should fix the error.